# Issue in calculating mean of n values of each column of a subset of data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am new to python trying to pre-process the data. I have a csv file with the following output:

```
       Time        A         B     C              
       05:00.9     50.0      0  0.148757      
       05:02.0     76.0      0  0.148757      
       Load        12:04:59      2.0                
       07:37.5      0.0      0  0.155029      
       07:38.6     70.0      0  0.155029      
       Load        12:07:36      2.0
```

Desired output:

```
       Time         A        B     C         
       05:00.9     50.0      0  0.148757     
       05:02.0     76.0      0  0.148757      
                   63        0  0.148575
       Load         12:04:59      2.0                
       07:37.5      0.0      0  0.155029      
       07:38.6     70.0      0  0.155029  
                   70.0      0  0.155029     
       Load        12:07:36      2.0
```

I need to calculate the mean of the of each column before load time is encountered in the csv file and store data in data frame.

I tried the below code. It iterates over the entire column but I need mean value before each Load time not average of Load time. Thanks

```
for row in df.iterrows():
       A=df['A'].mean()
       B=df['B'].mean()

       or 
      for row in df.iterrows():
      df2 = df.groupby(str.contains("Load")).mean()
      print(df2)
```

Comment: You should fix your desired output. The C average is not correct and why are there no average for the second set of times?

Comment: Thanks for point out this @Akaisteph7

Comment: Is the first snippet the content of the csv?

Comment: Yes its the content of the csv @Valentino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have read the `csv` into a `dataframe` - you can create **IDs** by checking whether or not a particular row contains the string *Load* in it -

```
df["Contains_String_Load"] = df.Time.str.contains("Load").astype('int')
#Above line will return a 1 if the row has Load, 0 otherwise
df["Group_ID"] = df.Contains_String_Load.cumsum()
df = df.loc[df.Contains_String_Load==0, :]
df.groupby("Group_ID").mean()
```

Returns this

```
             A    B         C     D  Contains_String_Load
Group_ID                                                 
0         63.0  0.0  0.148757  46.7                     0
1         35.0  0.0  0.155029  45.1                     0
```